# Android loading image before activity starts

Tags: android, loading

I want to show up a loading image before the activity starts. Is it possible? Or should I create the LoadingActivity class?

Answer (score 1):

Start the activity you want to load into, immediately call a `async` task, and while that is in `pre execute` create an overlay view that will stay until `postExecute` is called. At which point just dismiss the view

Comment: How to actually create an overlay view? can you provide some code? and the activity is Launcher activity so it's not needed to be started.

Comment: You want to start a loading activity before the launcher activity?

Comment: I just want to show the image before the launcher activity starts. Is it possible?

Comment: So you essentially want to have two splash screens then?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a loadingActivity class, or another Option would be to Show this loading Image in the same activity as the mainactivity and set the visibility of the loading Image to false as soon as all data is loaded

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you need splash screen. [Here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) you can read how to make it the best way.

Comment: Please don't leave answers that are entirely dependent on links. Links are volatile.